# Why should I use Cargo if "cargo build" is slower than running rustc directly?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I created a simple hello world program:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world");
}
```

When compiling the code using `rustc` vs `cargo build`, the cargo command appears slower. It takes *1.6s* for `cargo build` vs *1s* for `rustc`. See the timestamps on the right in the screenshot.

[image]

Why is this? Why should I still use cargo?

Comment: Can't you type out what's in your barely readable image?

Comment: `cargo` is not a compiler, it's a package manager. It runs `rustc` and does some extra work (e.g. resolves dependencies), so it can't be faster than bare `rustc`.

Comment: @Rob I added the time taken for both. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Pavel Strakhov Thanks. This is what I was looking for

Comment: That's like asking "why sould I use `make` while `gcc` is faster"...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As [Pavel Strakhov said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344347/pavel-strakhov)

> Cargo is not a compiler, it's a package manager. It runs `rustc` and does some extra work (e.g. resolves dependencies), so it can't be faster than bare `rustc`.

You can see this for yourself by running `cargo build --verbose`, which outputs the `rustc` command that cargo runs:

```
$ cargo build --verbose
   Compiling hw v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/hw)
     Running `rustc --crate-name hw src/main.rs --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=3c693c67d55ff970 -C extra-filename=-3c693c67d55ff970 --out-dir /private/tmp/hw/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/private/tmp/hw/target/debug/deps`
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.30 secs
```

> Why should I still use cargo

The output above shows one reason: Look at all those arguments passed to `rustc`. Do you know what each of them does? Do you *want* to know? Cargo abstracts some of the details away, allowing you to concentrate on the code.

Cargo also does **so much more than just invoking the compiler**. The biggest benefit to most people is that it [manages your dependencies based on versions](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html) and allows [publishing your own crates as well](http://doc.crates.io/crates-io.html). It also allows for [build scripts](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html) which run before your main compilation. It has easy ways of [running your tests](http://doc.crates.io/guide.html#tests) and examples.

More immediately useful, Cargo performs a check to see *if you should rebuild at all*:

```
$ time rustc src/main.rs
0:00.21
$ time rustc src/main.rs
0:00.22

$ time cargo build
0:00.41
$ time cargo build
0:00.09                   # Much better!
```